# Dynamic Safe 2D Jagged Array in C++

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, dynamic, jagged-arrays

How should I modify Dynamic Safe 2D array class into Dynamic Safe 2D jagged array class? I have read an article, it is best and safer to use dynamic safe or dynamic safe 2D array in order to avoid to initialize array of size less than 0 or array of size greater than it's original size. Most of the time, we can encounter such problems with excessive recursion like use of backtracking to find the path of maze.So I was trying to implement dynamic safe 2D jagged array class,but I don't understand how should I implement it ?

```
//Dynamic Safe 2D array class 
template <class T> 

class DS2DA 
{ 
  private: 
    T **Data; 
    int nRow; 
    int nCol; 

public: 

DS2DA () 
{ 
    nRow=0; 
    nCol=0;
    Data=nullptr; 
} 

DS2DA (int nRow,int nCol) 
{ 
    this->nRow=nRow; 
    this->nCol=nCol; 
    Data=new T * [nRow]; 

    for (int i=0;i<nRow;i++) 
    { 
        Data[i]=new T [nCol];
    }

    for (int i=0;i<nRow;i++) 
    { 
        for (int j=0;j<nCol;j++) 
        { 
            Data[i][j]=0; 
        }
    }
} 

T & operator () (int n1,int n2)   
{ 
    if ((n1<0 or n1>this->nRow) or (n2<0 or n2>this->nCol)) 
    { 
        cout<<"Array out of bound";
        exit (1); 
    } 

    else 
        return (Data[n1][n2]); 
 } 

};

//Driver Program 

int main () 
{
  DS2DA <double> obj1 (3,3); 
  int input; 

  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) 
  { 
    cout<<"Row "<<i+1<<endl; 

    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    { 
        cout<<"Enter Element "<<j+1<<":";
        cin>>input;
        obj1 (i,j)=input; 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: `template<typename T> using DS2DA = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that I miss the point, but as Swordfish wrote in his comment a `std::vector` containing `std::vector`s should do the trick.

If you want a two dimensional array with a width and height limit that grows dynamically try the following code:

```
template<class T>
class DynamicArray
{
public:
    DynamicArray()
        : rowCount(0),
        colCount(0)
    {}

    DynamicArray(size_t rowCount_, size_t colCount_)
        : rowCount(rowCount_),
        colCount(colCount_)
    {}

    const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const
    {
        if (row >= rowCount || col >= colCount)
            throw std::out_of_range("Row or column index out of range in " __FUNCTION__);

        static const T empty;

        if (data.size() <= row)
            return empty;
        const auto& rowData = data[row];
        if (rowData.size() <= col)
            return empty;
        return rowData[col];
    }

    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        if (row >= rowCount || col >= colCount)
            throw std::out_of_range("Row or column index out of range in " __FUNCTION__);

        if (data.size() <= row)
            data.resize(row + 1);
        auto& rowData = data[row];
        if (rowData.size() <= col)
            rowData.resize(col + 1);
        return rowData[col];
    }

public:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;
    size_t rowCount, colCount;
};
```

The array always starts without any rows or columns, but with a row/column limit (set to 0 in the default constructor).

Both () operators basically do the same: check row and column index and return the corresponding cell. However, while the non-const operator() resizes the jagged array to hold the given element, the const operator() simply returns a reference to an empty (default constructed) item. So you don't unnecessarily construct all missing items when iterating through the array.

Maybe an unordered_map with a coordinate pair as index would give you even better results depending on the use case. You could declare it with `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, T>`. A pair of ints should result in a pretty fast hashing function. With a very sparse array this would be my preferred solution.

Please be aware that the use of `__FUNCTION__` may need to be adjusted (or omitted) if you are not using Visual Studio. (in gcc `__FUNCTION__` expands to a function which returns the function name while Visual Studio expands it to a string containing the current function name).